# Can't access JavaScript static file through HTML using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using a Node.js server to show an HTML file. The HTML uses a Javascript file to get some info but I'm not being able to access that file. Here's my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swarm Profile</title>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my Node.js server file:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 9000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(res);
});


server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

What should I use to be able to access the script.js file?

Comment: You are returning `index.html` for every request.

Comment: Your code is only going to output the contents of ./index.html for all requests.  There is going to be another request for /js/script.js and you have to return that.  Look at the express.static in the express documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many static file handler modules already in node, take a look at: 
[Node static modules](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Modules#web-frameworks-static)

Most popular are: [Node-Paperboy](https://github.com/felixge/node-paperboy) and [Node-Static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static)

Using node static is as simple as:

```
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new(static.Server)('./public');

require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {

        file.serve(request, response);
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: express.static is built into express and does the job.  There is no need to pull another implementation in.

Comment: Oh, I apologize.  My brain registered this as using express, but it is not.

Comment: @Dave Exactly, with express this would be easier